# Gridsome's createPages and createManagedPages doesn't create viewable pages

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, gridsome

I have the following code in my `gridsome.server.js`:

```js
    api.createManagedPages(async ({ createPage }) => {
        const { data } = await axios.get('https://members-api.parliament.uk/api/Location/Constituency/Search?skip=0&take=20')
        data.items.forEach(item => {
            console.log(item.value.id);
            if (item.value.currentRepresentation !== null && typeof item.value.currentRepresentation === 'object') {
                createPage({
                    path: `/constituency/${item.value.id}`,
                    component: './src/templates/Constituency.vue',
                    context: {
                        id: item.value.id,
                        name: item.value.name,
                        startDate: item.value.startDate,
                        mpId: item.value.currentRepresentation.member.value.id,
                        mpName: item.value.currentRepresentation.member.value.nameDisplayAs,
                        mpParty: item.value.currentRepresentation.member.value.latestParty.name,
                        thumbnail: item.value.currentRepresentation.member.value.thumbnailUrl
                    }
                })
            }
        })
    })
```

Whether I change the code to createPages or createManagedPages I always get 404 not found errors when trying to visit */constituency/3292* for example.

That was previously. I've now revisted my code and when I run `gridsome serve` some update must have happened because I now get the following error:

```
TypeError: app.pages.data is not a function
    at createRoutes (/home/josh/Code/find-your-mp/node_modules/gridsome/lib/serve.js:57:34)
    at module.exports (/home/josh/Code/find-your-mp/node_modules/gridsome/lib/serve.js:29:18)
```

For some reason - even if I can console.log() the incoming data and it shows up it won't create the pages or the routes to the pages and gives the above error.

Answer (score 1):

gridsome serve command is very unstable and only maintained occasionally. Did you try to run your app with **gridsome develop** if you are working locally? If that doesn't work I suggest using [serve](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve) to run your app